# NodeJS : Electron & USB : error generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb, electron, libusb

I'm building an app using [`Electron`](http://electron.atom.io) and [`electron-usb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-usb), but I get the following error when I run **`npm start`** :

[image]

Here's the code that generates the error :

```
const usb = require('electron-usb');
```